# Scaffolding for Identity in .Net Core 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

The ['Scaffold Identity into a Razor project without existing authorization'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-without-existing-authorization) instructions apparently don't work for .Net 6.0.

The following code was automatically added to my Program.cs file as a result of doing Identity scaffolding for a Razor Pages app, using a context that did not previously exist:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).
AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext)<>();builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I got two error messages:

- IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for 'AddDefaultIdentity'.
- The name 'connectionString' does not exist in the current context.

What do you suggest, please?

Comment: The UseSqlServier is spelling mistake.  The correct is UseSqlServer .And in appsettings.json do you have "ConnectionStrings" for  "DefaultConnection" and ContextConnection ? And in Program.cs do you have var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); ?

Comment: Select the + button to create a new Data context class. Accept the default value or specify a class (for example, MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext). Have you do this step?

Comment: @QingGuo - I've just corrected the spelling mistake. I'll try your suggestion and let you know if it works. Thanks. As regards pressing the + button, that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

> IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for
> 'AddDefaultIdentity'.

Check your Packages.Do you have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` ? If not, add it  by NuGet Package Manager.

My Packages structure is below:

[image]

> The name 'connectionString' does not exist in the current context.

Do you have define the connectionString in Program.cs?

My code is below, you can refer it:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using WebI2.Data;
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
   //Get connectionString from appsetting.json
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebI2ContextConnection");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebI2Context>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebI2Context>();
```